# Radar Antenna Quantity and functional performance

Tags: radar

Millimeter wave radar SoC (system on a chip) are evolving from 4 to [72 antennas](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20180502005846/en/Vayyar-Imaging-Unveils-World%E2%80%99s-Advanced-CMOS-SOC) on a single chip.   Is there a simple (ELI5) explanation as to why 72 antennas (vs 4) are desirable?

My intuition says it improves either / both resolution and discrimination: the preferred explanation explains, in the simplest of terms qualitative terms that sharpens one's intuition and transitions \ follows-up with a mathematical treatise to the improvement.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE! I think this is a good question, but it might help if you could provide a reference (e.g. link to an external article).

Comment: Search term "phased array".